# Regular Expression Validation on TextBox in ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I want to validate user input in a textbox.  In a textbox, the user should only be able to put the street name, a space and then a number (e.g. road 65).

The requirements are:

- street name shall start with letters
- then it should be a space
- then it should be a number

What is a validation Regular Expression for this?

I am using `RegularExpressionValidator` in ASP .NET.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidatorStreet" runat="server"
         ErrorMessage="This is wrong!" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z\s][0-9]$"
        ControlToValidate="streettxt"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator><br />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression is only matching one character in `[a-zA-Z\s]` followed by one character in `[0-9]`, so it would match `"r6"` or `" 6"` or `"Z8"` but not `"road 65"`.

---

Since you want to match at least one or more letters, followed by one whitespace character, and finally one or more digits, try:

```
ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z]+\s[0-9]+$"
```

#### Explanation:

- Will match: `"road 65"`, `"qWerTy 6"`, or `"q 23983049823948"`
- Will ***not*** match: `"road     65"`, `"  road 65"`, nor `"road65"`
- `^` asserts position at start of the string
- `[a-zA-Z]+` match a single character between `a-z` or `A-Z` between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible
- `\s` match any single white space character
- `[0-9]+` match a single character between `0-9` between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible
- `$` assert position at end of the string

---

#### Notes:

If you want to match when there is between one and unlimited whitespace characters, add the quantifier onto `\s+`:

```
ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z]+\s+[0-9]+$"
```

which will match both `"road 65"` and  `"road      65"` but not `"road65"`.